# MoveIt custom capability error

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I am working on a custom-made (not by me) moveit capability on Moveit and Ros Kinetic and I am encountering an error that I don't manage to understand. As an information, I am working on Rviz with fake execution.

The pick is getting preempted due to an error here (https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/c106f20c1302ed75505a05141b3eb9767d5f4656/moveit_ros/planning/plan_execution/src/plan_execution.cpp --> line 502 : Execution of path-completion side-effect failed. Preempting). The capability is strongly based on the pick_place_action_capability from Moveit. I just want to understand what this error means (change in scene, planning that isn't feasible, etc.) in order to be able to debug the real cause. I can see that the plan is getting well (I can preview it if I do a plan only). And also on Rviz the pick seems to go all the way to the end (the gripper is grasping the object well).But at the moment the gripper close, it is preempted.

Can anyone enlight me about this error ?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348991/moveit-custom-capability-error/) by [Madcreator](https://answers.ros.org/users/51269/madcreator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2020-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer as given in https://answers.ros.org/question/351997/moveit-task-constructor-custom-stages/ where the question got mixed up:

The error you refer to does not mean anything but that the custom function you passed in to execute between trajectory segments returned false. For MTC's default ExecuteTaskSolutionCapability, the function is set to try to apply the next expected planning scene (change) to the PlanningScene of move_group. That might fail for a variety of reasons, among them unexpected changes to the scene and an ill-formed planning scene message. You should be able to get more constructive feedback from the DEBUG loggers of the PlanningScene class.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2020-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0